# Como recuperar dados enviados de um requisição post no angular

Tags: php, ajax, angularjs

Estou fazendo uma requisição post para um arquivo php que necessita de algum dados que são mandados pela requisição. Minha dúvida é como recuperar essas informações que estão sendo enviadas na requisição

Meu código para a requisição está assim:

```
//pego a descricao no compa input
var dados = {"descricao": $('#descricao').val()};

$scope.getData = function() {
    $http.post('data.php', dados).success(function(data) {
        ...
        console.log(data);
    }).error(function(data) {
        ...
        console.log(data);
    });
```

Como faria para pegar essas informação no arquivo 'data.php'?

`var_dump($_POST);` me retorna um array vazio: `array(0) { }`

Comment: @Sergio, consegui achar uma solução. Fiz desse modo:
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
Dessa forma consigo acessar as informações passadas pela requisição

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solução é a seguinte:

```
$post = file_get_contents("php://input");
$json = json_dencode($post);
```

Answer (score 2):

Outra saída seria esta:

```
//pego a descricao no compa input
var dados = {"descricao": $('#descricao').val()};

$scope.getData = function() {
  $http.post('data.php', dados).success(function(data) {
    ...
    console.log(data);
  }).error(function(data) {
      ...
     console.log(data);
  }).config(['$httpProvider',function($httpProvider){
    $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest.push(
            function(data){
                var requestStr;
                if (data) {
                    data = JSON.parse(data);
                    for (var key in data) {
                        if (requestStr) {
                            requestStr += '&' + key + '=' + data[key];
                        }else{
                            requestStr = key + '=' + data[key];
                        }
                    }
                }
                return requestStr;
            }
        );
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'; 
}]);
```